# Does Handbrake support PIP (picture in picture)?

Tags: handbrake

I am trying to determine whether Handbrake can support PIP (picture in picture).  I've looked through this site, and several FAQ across the internet but wasn't able to find anything whether it does support it.  I am fine with HandbrakeCLI as well.  Any information would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you look at the Handbrake CLI docs it has no support or features for PIP.  Handbrake CLI .. https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide ..

Comment: Thanks, I just need assurance that it did/did not have any.